# aws Presigned Url doesn't support videos that are more than 1 minute long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YUmi.png)When I tried creating Presigned URLs for my videos in s3 some of the video's presigned urls don't work. and It turned out that only URl of videos that are more then 1 minute long. Is there a problem  on my side while creating the url or is it a restriction in AWS presigned URLs

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Maybe the expiration of the link is set to 1 minute meaning that if I start watching the video it will not able to retrieve data after 1 minute of watching. What error, how do you create the urls?

Comment: I get no error ! when I open the link it is just a black empty video player ! and No I create Presigned URL's with 7 days expiration date

Comment: You ll find the screenshot attached to my question

Answer (score 0):

For S3 all files are object there is no any specific rule for image and video maybe your MIME type are property set because if there is signed url issue AWS provide the error access denied. you can confirm this with make this video pubic and try to run it I am sure after public access its not play so check below check points

1. Check the video MIME type
2. Check Video size its property uploaded or not
3. If you upload video from local machine try to play is it correct formatted means play as expected or not.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using readStream ?

[rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#readfilepath-encodingpromise)

Worked for me with having larger Videos or Images

Comment: Is it an alternative to Presigned url ? I ll look into it thanks